# Why is this program skipping passed the first to the else when I am inputting 'Y'?

Tags: c, if-statement

I can't seem to find where the error is in this code. When I input 'Y' it is skipping over the first if statement and calculating the else statement below it. Do I have a dangling else problem or is something else? I am a beginner so I wouldn't know it if I saw it. The code doesn't have to be pretty or perfect, it only has to work. Do I need an if else statement instead of an if? When i use an if else it tells me I have a syntax error. As you can see I am trying to calculate discounts and sales tax depending on whether or not the buyer is a teacher. How much more do I have to type to submit a question. I am new to this also so I apologize if it is not formatted correctly. If the purchase price is greater than 100 the discount is 12% if less than 100 the discount is 10%. The program is to print out a receipt with the discount, tax and total price.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>``
#define SALES_TAX 0.05
#define REG_DISCOUNT 0.10
#define DISCOUNT 0.12

int main()
{
    double price, discount,total,x,tax;

    printf("Enter purchase total=>");
    scanf("%lf",&total);
    printf("If you are a teacher enter Y if not enter N=>");
    scanf("%lf",&x);

    if(x=='Y'){

        if(total<100)
            {
            discount = total * REG_DISCOUNT;
            tax = (total - discount)* SALES_TAX;
            price = total - discount + tax;
            }
        else{
            discount = total * DISCOUNT;
            tax = (total - discount)* SALES_TAX;
            price = total + tax - discount;

            }
        printf("The total price of your items is = $%.2f.\n",total);
                    printf("Your 12 percent discount = $%.2f.\n",discount);
                    printf("You're total tax is $%.2f.\n",tax);
                    printf("You're final purchase price is $%.2f.\n",price);
    }
    else {
        tax = total * SALES_TAX;
        price = total + tax;
        printf("The total price of your items is $%.2f.\n",total);
        printf("Your total tax is $%.2f.\n",tax);
        printf("Your total purchase price with tax is $%.2f.\n",price);
        }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: TL; DR; Use a debugger.

Comment: You're comparing a double to a character; that won't work. In fact, your compiler will probably show a warning: don't ignore warnings until you know exactly why you ignore them.

Comment: ok so it should be scanf("%c", &x) instead?

Comment: or scan("%char", &x) rather

Comment: With your suggested change, you'd still be trying to read a character into a double. Use a different data type for storing the `Y` or `N`.

Comment: `char x;`... `scanf(" %c",  &x);`

Answer (score 0):

The scanf statement that reads the string X has a format code that means floating point. Try using %s

Comment: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat=]
  scanf("%s",&x);
        ^

Comment: I don't know why it keeps saying 'argument 2 has type double' when I am reading it in as a character

Comment: @BryceMarshall Because `x` is a double.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your variable declarations to make X a char:

```
double price, discount,total,tax;
char   x;
```

Now when you do 'scanf(%c, &x)' x will have the correct type and your check 'if(x=='Y') will wok as expected.